# ns2 ubunt Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ns2

I write a tcl script to simulate network using ns2. 
When I set 20MB for each flow size, ns2 reply "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

But when I set 5MB, it works!
Why?

Answer (score 1):

please provide more information. First of all, use gdb and run ns2 in gdb. Then, whenever ns2 crashes, you can use backtrace to see in which method and class the crash happens. Then, you can modify the method to support what you need.

Answer (score 0):

---

NS-2 has some limitations http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/system-configuration-required-for-ns2-on-linux-to-handle-large-simulations-4175552241/#2

... and [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/error-while-executing-ns2-4175530493/#2) .

If you want to run complex simulations, please consider the commercial OPNET. Other alternatives : ns3, OMNeT++, Castalia.

---